# Attempting to set up a delegate for a custom AlertControlView

Tags: ios, swiftui, delegates

My code for the alert is as follows:

```
struct AlertControlView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var textString: String
    @Binding var showAlert: Bool

    var title: String
    var message: String

    // Make sure that, this fuction returns UIViewController, instead of UIAlertController.
    // Because UIAlertController gets presented on UIViewController
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertControlView>) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController() // Container on which UIAlertContoller presents
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AlertControlView>) {
    
        // Make sure that Alert instance exist after View's body get re-rendered
        guard context.coordinator.alert == nil else { return }
    
        if self.showAlert {
        
            // Create UIAlertController instance that is gonna present on UIViewController
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            context.coordinator.alert = alert
        
            // Adds UITextField & make sure that coordinator is delegate to UITextField.
            alert.addTextField { textField in
                textField.placeholder = "Enter some text"
                textField.text = self.textString            // setting initial value
                textField.delegate = context.coordinator    // using coordinator as delegate
            }
        
            // As usual adding actions
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "") , style: .destructive) { _ in
            
                // On dismiss, SiwftUI view's two-way binding variable must be update (setting false) means, remove Alert's View from UI
                alert.dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.showAlert = false
                }
            })
        
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Submit", comment: ""), style: .default) { _ in
                // On submit action, get texts from TextField & set it on SwiftUI View's two-way binding varaible `textString` so that View receives enter response.
                if let textField = alert.textFields?.first, let text = textField.text {
                    self.textString = text
                }
            
                alert.dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.showAlert = false
                }
            })
        
            // Most important, must be dispatched on Main thread,
            // Curious? then remove `DispatchQueue.main.async` & find out yourself, Dont be lazy
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // must be async !!
                uiViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.showAlert = false  // hide holder after alert dismiss
                    context.coordinator.alert = nil
                })
            
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> AlertControlView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
        // Holds reference of UIAlertController, so that when `body` of view gets re-rendered so that Alert should not disappear
        var alert: UIAlertController?
    
        // Holds back reference to SwiftUI's View
        var control: AlertControlView
    
        init(_ control: AlertControlView) {
            self.control = control
        }
    
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            textField.text =  textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "^0+", with: "")
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if let text = textField.text as NSString? {
                self.control.textString = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            } else {
                self.control.textString = ""
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Its being called as such:

```
@State var changePassword = false

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {

        HStack {
                    
            Text("Password")
                    
            Spacer()
                    
            Text(String(editingPool.password))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .font(.callout)
                    
            Button(action: {
                    
                changePassword.toggle()
                        
            }) {
                    
                Text("Change")
                    
            }
        
        }
        
        if self.changePassword {
                        
            AlertControlView(textString: $editingPool.password,
                showAlert: $changePassword,
                title: "Change Pool Password",
                message: "Enter the new pool password.")
    
        }
    }
}
```

I cant seem to get the shouldChangeCharactersIn function to get called, or any of the begin, end or onchange functions either?

Comment: `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `shouldChangeCharactersIn` work fine for me with that code and presenting it from a simple `SwiftUI` View.

Comment: I am using it as an alert to the user to enter a new password. I can not get either of the two functions to get called?

Comment: @jnpdx code added